# Fragment getActivity not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, android-context

I am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/) tutorial, and and trying to create a profile page for each individual user instead of albums. However, I am using fragments instead of activities and realise my code will be abit different to the tutorial.

I have used the Android developer documentation and my own knowledge to fix the majority of bugs transferring from an activity to a fragment, however I can not seem to find the solution to this one, any help is appreciated.

I have the below code that works fine:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

But when I try to add to the recycler view I get an error:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
```

> Cant resolve symbol GridSpacingItemDecoration
>
> Cant resolve method dpToPx(int)

Here is its class as requested

```
 public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy `GridSpacingItemDecoration` and `dpToPx()` to your fragment.

Comment: No worries I fixed the problem, it was due to another class I had created

Comment: So, is your problem solved now? @UCLCoder

Answer (score 0):

Make this method private to public

Comment: Requesting of details, please put it up in a comment, instead of answer! Not a good practice!

Comment: @UCLCoder,if my suggestion is also working then please accept the answer so that oter people can get help